# How do I get this SQL command to print with the SUM listed in ascending order?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

```
SELECT Order_Date, Sum(Number_Ordered) AS TotalPartsOrderdforDay
FROM Orders, Order_Line
WHERE Orders.Order_Number=Order_Line.Order_Number
GROUP BY Order_Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `join` syntax!

```
SELECT o.Order_Date, Sum(Number_Ordered) AS TotalPartsOrderdforDay
FROM Orders o JOIN
     Order_Line ol
     ON o.Order_Number = ol.Order_Number
GROUP BY o.Order_Date
ORDER BY TotalPartsOrderdforDay;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You can use the column alias in the `ORDER BY`.
- It is best practice to qualify all column references in a query, particularly if more than one table is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `order by` clause:

```
SELECT Order_Date, Sum(Number_Ordered) AS TotalPartsOrderdforDay
FROM Orders, Order_Line
WHERE Orders.Order_Number=Order_Line.Order_Number
GROUP BY Order_Date
ORDER BY 2 ASC;
```

Side note: implicit joins (having more than one term in the `from` clause) is an outdated practice, and you'd probably be better served to use an explicit `join`:

```
SELECT   Order_Date, Sum(Number_Ordered) AS TotalPartsOrderdforDay
FROM     Orders
JOIN     Order_Line ON Orders.Order_Number = Order_Line.Order_Number
GROUP BY Order_Date
ORDER BY 2 ASC;
```